# How to stop typing break from interrupting VLC?

Tags: vlc, typing-break

When I watch a DVD in vlc, the typing break will kick in even though I haven't touched the keyboard or mouse for over half an hour. This is a bit annoying ... Does anyone know how to stop this happening?

Comment: I think you might have found a bug, so maybe you might want to report it.

Comment: as a temporary workaround, see if the inhibitor applet fixes this.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Workrave](http://www.workrave.org/). It's infinitely more customizable than Ubuntu's typing break and should play nicely with VLC. You can install it using Ubuntu Software Center.
But also look into Shungun's suggestion and try the Inhibit Applet. You'll probably love it anyway if you're into watching movies.